# how to empty /dev/sda3 in linux

Tags: linux

I have zero knowlloge in linux and I have the issue "No space left on device". df -i output looks like this:
[image]

It looks for me that **dev/sda3** is 100% full.
My question is how to find out which files belong to dev/sda3 so that I can remove them to have free space on this device.

Comment: This kind of question is more suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) the Linux tags here are for programming related questions only

Comment: Mounted on `/` := it is your **root file system**.

Comment: There is only one line with `sda3`, which is the root file system. The usage is 100% (column 5). BTW: do not make screenshots of text data.

Comment: `sda3` is mounted on `/`. All files belong to sda3 _except_ files at `/dev` `/run` `/sys` `/data` `/oracle` etc.. other mounted directories.

Comment: Ronald to add to @ceving 's comment, if you copy text data from your terminal and add four spaces in front of each line in your favorite text editor it will display in a code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first we need a copy of sda3's contents without everything mounted on top of it (e.g. /boot/efi from sda1, /data from sdd, etc)

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
```

Now it's easy, if slow, to get a sorted smallest-to-biggest list of just sda3's contents

```
du /mnt/root | sort -u -n > /data/bigfiles.txt
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem. Should I remove the created directory mnt/root afterwards?

Comment: It's your preference whether you remove it after you unmount it with `umount /mnt/root` as root. A lot of people keep a lot of mount point folders inside /mnt and /media, the empty folders are harmless as long as you've unmounted.

Comment: I should add, unmounting the bind mount (which is just an alias without garbage mounted on top of it) won't impact your underlying filesystem.

Comment: Also if you plan on doing this again and add an fstab entry (which I won't go into but which would allow you to `mount /mnt/root`), in that case you would _not_ want to remove the empty directory.

Comment: Instead of the [bind mount](/https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) you can just use [`du -x`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html).

Comment: I forgot about that, thanks @ceving :) That said it was my suspicion Ronald may be wanting to look through the filesystem other ways since du takes quite a while to do its magic. Nonetheless du -x is a very cool tool and I am glad you reminded me of that.